# PHP Page not getting data sent and not echoing

Tags: php, jquery

I have a simple setup that takes a hex value from a color picker converts it to RGB and then sends it to a PHP script from the HTML. The recieving file is not echoing and it is not refreshing either. I probably am doing something wrong but wanted to run it by someone just in case.

### Java/Jquery

```
function hexToRgb(hex) {
    var result = /^#?([a-f\d]{2})([a-f\d]{2})([a-f\d]{2})$/i.exec(hex);
    return result ? {
        r: parseInt(result[1], 16),
        g: parseInt(result[2], 16),
        b: parseInt(result[3], 16)
    } : null;
}
$(document).ready(function() {
    var picker = $.farbtastic('#picker');
    picker.linkTo(function onColorChange(color) {
        var finalcolor=hexToRgb(color);
        console.log(finalcolor,"helloworld");

        $.post("imagedisplay.php", {var_value: finalcolor});

    });
});
```

### RECIEVING PHP

```
<?php
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')
{
    $hex=$_POST['var_value'];
    echo '$hex';
}
?>
```

Comment: Did you check with your console to make sure the $_POST headers were being sent properly? Did you try `var_dump($_POST);` at the very top of the PHP script?

Comment: For one, `echo '$hex';` will literally print just that. Do `echo $hex;` instead.

Comment: You have no callback function in your `$.post`, so it doesn't do anything with the response from PHP.

Comment: [difference between single and double quotes in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3446216/what-is-the-difference-between-single-quoted-and-double-quoted-strings-in-php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use AJAX, the page is not refreshed automatically (that's generally the reason you use AJAX instead of normal form submission). You need a callback function in `$.post` to do something with the response from PHP:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var picker = $.farbtastic('#picker');
    picker.linkTo(function onColorChange(color) {
        var finalcolor=hexToRgb(color);
        console.log(finalcolor,"helloworld");

        $.post("imagedisplay.php", {var_value: finalcolor}, function(response) {
            alert('PHP said: ' + response);
        });
    });
});
```

In your PHP, `$hex` is an associative array. You can't echo an array, use:

```
print_r($hex);
```

Comment: Ok the alert back said PHP Said: Array Not Sure what that means But I am guessing something is not working

Comment: That will happen if you try to echo a variable that contains an array rather than a string.

Comment: With the PHP script you posted, I would expect it to alert `PHP said: $hex`. I don't know where `Array` is coming from, unless your PHP is different.

Comment: It did that once, then it just kept saying array. All I am passing is a RGB converted from a hex value.

Comment: I see what's going on. `hexToRgb` returns a Javascript object. When this gets sent to PHP, `$_POST['var_value']` is an associative array. So `echo $hex` prints `Array`.

Comment: Use `print_r($hex)` instead of `echo $hex`.

Comment: [output of php](http://preview.88kcikfcuw4mfgvi8ckrxvjrndu6jemi01t025rhda6skyb9.box.codeanywhere.com/)  There we go now it's outputting right.